# how to fix deopted-into-client-rendering during next build

Tags: next.js

I have a statically generated page with the below.
I do not understand why when using npm run build, the page is showing as deopted-into-client-rendering.

```
export const dynamicParams = true;

export const revalidate = 60;

export async function generateStaticParams() {
 const url = process.env.EDC_API_BASEURL + `/productId`;
 const prodResp = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
 });

 const prodList = (await prodResp.json()) as productId[];

 return prodList.map((p: productId) => {
    return { id: p.id.toString() };
  });
 }
```

The actual page:

```
export default async function ProductOverviewPage({
 params
 }: {
 params: { id: string };
 }) {
 return <div>product overview</div>
 );
```

Comment: @DanielW. I have removed the link from the title and changed to a proper question